# Customising log in form

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap

I took the Spring Security example from  the Spring framework website, and I make it to work. Now I have to extend it so I can use a log in form customized by me. I think I need to change this method:

> protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)

Does anyone know how to do this?`

```
    package hello;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configurers.GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

     @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();


    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends
            GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=otherpeople")
                    .groupSearchBase("ou=groups").contextSource()
                    .ldif("classpath:test-server.ldif");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is [a guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html) on the Spring docs site which covers exactly this topic.

Comment: thank you, I am now looking into it.